# Load balancing in Tomcat in 64-bit OS

Tags: performance, tomcat, jvm, load-balancing

I have a web application and required load balancing in Tomcat.
My hardware spec is 5 unit of 32 GB RAM quad-core processors 64 bit OS.

Should I have

1. 5 Tomcats, one in each machine with -Xmx around 30GB and higher maxThreads
2. A bigger number of Tomcats with lower -Xmx, e.g. 25 Tomcats, 5 in each machine with -Xmx around 6GB and default maxThreads

I have load balancer using mod_proxy_balancer before Tomcats. Let assume there is no bottle neck at database layer to simplify the situation.

Let me know if you need more info.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't know about this load balancing stuff, but you might get a faster answer from http://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 0):

I see no benefit to having multiple Tomcats per machine, unless they happened to be serving different things and you wanted to take them down independently. Or if you anticipate crashes and you want to make sure at least some instances on a machine are isolated. Other than that, there's no apparent benefit. Certainly not from a performance standpoint, which is what I think you're asking.

There's a big downside to multiple Tomcats, which is that each has a fixed amount of memory. If your app happens to need a larger amount for a short period of time, you'll get Out of Memory errors. There's a greater margin of error when you have one big memory space.

Also, you'll find monitoring to be a bigger hassle with a larger number of instances.

If you've got multiple Tomcats, then they all have to run on different ports, or you've got to front them with something on each machine. In either case, it leads to unnecessary complexity.

I vote for one Tomcat per machine.

Comment: The author for http://www.theserverside.com/news/1363681/Scaling-Your-Java-EE-Applications said 12GB max ram cause high pause time during gc and recommend to use only 3GB. He did not share his gc setting so I am not sure can it be fine-tuned.